# Sound output device recognized, but no audio

Tags: sound, 19.04

This is a follow-up to this earlier question: [No sound output device recognized by PulseAudio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/795198/audio-devices-detected-but-no-sound-outputting)

In the prior question, eventually I didn't get any useful tips, so I just let the tablet sit in a corner for a few months. Unfortunately, recently my primary PC broke and the tablet is the only device on hand that can do (a part of) its job, so today I turned it on again, and found out that 19.04 is available. I accepted the upgrade, and after it's done, surprisingly I found out that it improves the situation on audio... somewhat.

The biggest change here is that the ES8316 sound card is finally gloablly (?) recognized. Settings now acknowledges more output devices, and PulseAudio sees the card as well:

```
~$ pacmd list-cards
2 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_02.0-platform-hdmi-lpe-audio>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio"
        alsa.long_card_name = "Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hdmi_lpe_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:02.0-platform-hdmi-lpe-audio"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/hdmi-lpe-audio/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "22b0"
        device.product.name = "Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Configuration Registers"
        device.string = "1"
        device.description = "Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Configuration Registers"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5900, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5700, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: unknown)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:hdmi-stereo-extra2>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_02.0-platform-hdmi-lpe-audio.hdmi-stereo-extra2/#1: Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Configuration Registers Digital Stereo (HDMI 3)
    sources:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_02.0-platform-hdmi-lpe-audio.hdmi-stereo-extra2.monitor/#2: Monitor of Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Configuration Registers Digital Stereo (HDMI 3)
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
    index: 1
    name: <alsa_card.platform-bytcht_es8316>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 8
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "bytcht-es8316"
        alsa.long_card_name = "Insyde-CherryTrail"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_soc_sst_byt_cht_es8316"
        device.bus_path = "platform-bytcht_es8316"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/808622A8:00/bytcht_es8316/sound/card0"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
    profiles:
        input:analog-mono: Analog Mono Input (priority 7, available: unknown)
        output:stereo-fallback: Stereo Output (priority 5100, available: unknown)
        output:stereo-fallback+input:analog-mono: Stereo Output + Analog Mono Input (priority 5107, available: unknown)
        output:multichannel-output: Multichannel Output (priority 100, available: unknown)
        output:multichannel-output+input:analog-mono: Multichannel Output + Analog Mono Input (priority 107, available: unknown)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:stereo-fallback+input:analog-mono>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.platform-bytcht_es8316.stereo-fallback/#0: Built-in Audio Stereo
    sources:
        alsa_output.platform-bytcht_es8316.stereo-fallback.monitor/#0: Monitor of Built-in Audio Stereo
        alsa_input.platform-bytcht_es8316.analog-mono/#1: Built-in Audio Analog Mono
    ports:
        analog-input: Analog Input (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:

        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
        multichannel-output: Multichannel Output (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
```

I can now play a wav file with `aplay` without it erroring out:

```
~$ aplay -D plughw:CARD=bytchtes8316,DEV=0 ./wz/01-10.wav 
Playing WAVE './wz/01-10.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 16000 Hz, Mono
```

Even the sound amplitude indicator bar in `pavucontrol` acts correctly against the audio I'm playing.

However, I just can't hear anything in my headphones. Sound test, playing audio via system media player or `aplay`, all without a sound. HDMI audio works as usual, but that's not what I wanted.

I've tried the common tricks with PA/ALSA, restarting ALSA/PA, clearing/rebuilding PA config, using `alsamixer` or `pavucontrol`, to no avail.

**What's next?**

---

I followed the [community sound troubleshooting guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) where possible, and here are the 2 crucial outputs: [Step 3](https://del.dog/tevucicufa) (alsa-info), [Step 4](https://del.dog/avojowotan) (diagnostic commands). I'll also make a WTG USB stick soon and check audio under Windows if possible.

---

Note that, since I've left the tablet idle for some time, I can't be 100% sure that the port isn't broken. This tablet no longer has Windows installed on it, and has too little space to install one, and as a result I can't test it under Windows. If you think it's necessary to verify whether the port hardware still works, please suggest an alternative way to test it.

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: @angelcervera Nope. I didn't get to verify the integrity of the port either, as the tablet refuses to recognize any Windows boot disk (weird huh?), which is why I turned to Ubuntu in the first place.